# Show that every acyclic graph has at least two vertices with degree less than 2

Tags: graph-theory

Show that every non-trivial acyclic graph has at least two vertices with degree less than 2.

**Attempt:** We know that if every vertex of $G$ has a degree at least 2 then $G$ contains a cycle. Now, since $G$ is acyclic $G$ has at least one vertex (say, v_1) with degree 0 or 1. I am not sure how to proceed further.

Can I delete the vertex $v_1$ from $G$ and claim that $G-\{v_1\}$ is also acyclic and use some recursive argument.

Comment: I should have mentioned Every non-trivial graph. My Bad.

Answer (score 2):

The claim **is not true**. The graph with a single vertex and no edges is acyclic but *does not* have two vertices of any description.

However, if you add an assumption that the graph has at least two vertices, then your strategy looks sound. A vertex of degree $0$ or $1$ is cannot be part of a cycle, so deleting that vertex cannot make the graph acyclic if it was not *already* acyclic. You should be able to phrase it as an *induction on the number of vertices in the graph*.

Comment: If we use induction we will end up proving every vertex has degree 0 or 1, is not it?

Comment: @Babai: Hopefully not, since that is not true. Note that a vertex with degree 1 in $G\setminus \{v_1\}$ may have its degree increased by 1 when you reattach $v_1$.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, if $G$ is acyclic, then $G$ is a forest. WLOG, suppose $G$ is connected. Then $G$ is a tree and therefore, we have $n = e+1$. We also know that by Handshaking Lemma, we have
$$2e = \sum_{i =1}^nd(v_i)$$
Which implies that 
$$2(n-1) = \sum_{i =1}^nd(v_i) \implies 2n-2 = \sum_{i =1}^nd(v_i)$$
Can you conclude your result from here?

Comment: Is it possible to prove without using the fact that for a tree $n=e+1$?

Comment: For this argument, I don't think so. But maybe you can say something like "any connected acyclic graph with $n$ vertices can be constructed by adding a vertex $v$ and edge incident to $v$ to some graph with $n-1$ vertices". Then you can use induction.